# How to clear attribute columns from a Shapefile?

Tags: qgis, vector, sextante

I want to clear all columns from a SHP. Only need geometry of features. I use QGIS and Sextante with grass and saga. Is there any tool for this job...

Answer (score 9):

There are several tools you can use to Drop\delete columns.

**1 - Atribute table "delete column" tool**

- Open layer's attribute table;
- Start editing;
- Click on "delete columns" icon;
- Select several columns using Pressing Ctrl;
- Click ok;
- Stop\Save editing;

[image]

**2 - Use Table Manager Plugin**

- Install [Table Manager Plugin](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/tablemanager/) using Plugins > fetch python plugins;
- Click on the plugin Icon or in Vector > Table manager > Table manager;
- Select several columns\fields using Pressing Ctrl;
- click on delete;
- Ok

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A simple way of getting rid of the attributes is to rightclick on the layer -> `Save As...` and check `Surpress attribute creation`.

If you have many files, you could use:

> ogr2ogr -select field_list destination_file source_file

to select fields you want (default is all!)